# SQL for counting rows and categorize

Tags: sql, rowcount

Is it possible to do the following for `count >=3,4,5,6,7,8` etc.
rather than repeating the entire code for each count category

```
Insert into OnePlus (SELECT DISTINCT Id, Name, COUNT(DISTINCT StartDate) AS OnePlusDays
    FROM DataTable
    HAVING OnePlusDays >= 1
    GROUP BY Id, Name)

Insert into TwoPlus (SELECT DISTINCT Id, Name, COUNT(DISTINCT StartDate) AS TwoPlusDays
    FROM DataTable
    HAVING TwoPlusDays >= 2
    GROUP BY Id, Name)
```

Finally

```
SELECT Id, Name, "1+" AS Categories
    FROM OnePlus
UNION
    SELECT Id, Name, "2+" AS Categories
    FROM TwoPlus
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: you cannot insert into multiple tables in only one single statement

Comment: Your syntax is really weird. insert into tablename select etc it is. (Test here http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/index.tml). Don't mix distinct and group by. (Result is distinct already in your case after the group by!) UNION ALL is what you want.

Comment: What exactly you need to do!

Comment: Sorry my SQL syntax was not correct, but basically I wanted to know if I can categorize into 1+, 2+, 3+ etc and at the end union it into one table.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You mention only sql in the tags. Depending on MySql or SQL Server, you may need to change the Cast/Convert and Concatenation. But this query may help. You really don't need to put a Distinct on top a group by, the fact that you are grouping by, means only distinct values and their counts will be fetched.

Of course, the table OnePlus, is really what you call Categories.

```
Insert into OnePlus 
   SELECT Id, Name, convert(varchar(10), COUNT(DISTINCT StartDate) ) + "+" AS Categories
    FROM DataTable
    GROUP BY Id, Name
```

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL you can write as:

```
SELECT Id, 
       NAME , -- make sure you write case statement in desc order
       CASE WHEN PlusDays > = 2 THEN '2+' 
            WHEN PlusDays > = 1 THEN '1+' END AS Categories
FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT Id, Name, COUNT(DISTINCT StartDate) PlusDays
FROM @DataTable
GROUP BY Id, Name
) AS T 
ORDER BY Id asc
```

Comment: Thank you Deepshikha. that helped me to get an idea what I need to do.